# Querying data table to get particular row in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have data table which has  columns namely Amount,StartDate. I am trying to get particular amount value from Amount based on StartDate.

My code is as follows:

```
DataTable dtt =_dstt.Tables[0];
var res = from r in dtt.AsEnumerable()
          where  r.Field("StartDate") == Convert.ToDateTime(drpStartYear.SelectedValue));
          select r.Field("Amount");
```

I am getting following error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(System.Data.DataRow, int)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

_dsst is DataSet which I populate from database.

Is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
DataTable dtt =_dstt.Tables[0];
var res = from r in dtt.AsEnumerable()
where  r.Field<DateTime>("StartDate") == Convert.ToDateTime(drpStartYear.SelectedValue));
select r.Field<Double>("Amount");
```

You need to specify the DataType of column like this `r.Field<YourType>("ColumnName")`

Comment: Thanks to all, I was missing datatype casting

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = from r in dtt.AsEnumerable()
          where  r.Field<DateTime>("StartDate") == Convert.ToDateTime(drpStartYear.SelectedValue));
          select r.Field<double>("Amount");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dtt =_dstt.Tables[0];
var res = from r in dtt.AsEnumerable()
          where  r.Field<type>("StartDate") == Convert.ToDateTime(drpStartYear.SelectedValue));
          select r.Field<type>("Amount");
```

type in <> will be the type of arguement you are using